# DIY website stats/analytics

Tags: web-applications, statistics, analytics

I'd like to keep some basic information about some of the web pages.

The information I'm looking to keep is very minimal, and the likes of Google analytics are overkill, and make it hard to integrate results into the page.

I'd like to keep timestamp,ip and browser information to calculate accurate information about the number of visits per day/week/month/year as well as be able to get in idea of where visitors are coming from.

Is it better to store this information in a flat-file for all pages, flat-file per page tracked or relational database?

Comment: I'm leaning toward a per/page flat file because writing and retrieving info is probably the fastest, and would not bloat the database I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused when you say "integrate results into the page."  Do you want to somehow publicly display your traffic or do you just want a user friendly and simple interface to see things?

When you say "Is it better to store this information in a flat-file for all pages, flat-file per page tracked or relational database?" - this also confuses me as, if you have cPanel or most any other type of server it already automatically stores log files of each user's interaction with the server/website.  The log file is a "flat-file for all pages" + anything else the user does.  Really no matter how much traffic you're getting you're server is going to be logging it into a file.  There's not much need to get into databases unless you're doing other stuff.  I cover the log file in Option B.

I'm trying to gauge your expertise, but I'll just list the ways I generally do things.  Maybe one will help.

**Option A** is for a fairly new user/admin of a website (but may suite you perfectly) &

**Option B** is for one who is a bit more advanced, but would display the information you want in a nice excel spreadsheet once formatted.  It also requires quite a few more steps.  I go into detail with each one not knowing your level of expertise; apologizes if it's redundant.

**Option A)** Statcounter.com - it's super easy to install, free, no CC upfront, covers everything you seem to need, and scalable.  Even if you don't know how to copy and paste code into a page they have a nice simple guide for you.  It's free up to a certain amount of visitors (I believe they'll hold the most recent 250) then you just pay a small fee.  I believe the fee is around $10 per year to hold a log of the last 5000 visitors or so and it goes up from there very reasonably.

You can also only put it on select pages like you seem to want to do.

Statcounter will collect a little more than just the Timestamp, IP, browser information, and referring URL, but not much more to the point you feel inundated like with Google Analytics - it may suit your needs perfectly.  The user interface is very user-friendly as well.

Option B) A more accurate method that requires a bit more experience/effort would be to download your server logs.  This may not be a any use to you, but here goes.

I'm not sure what type of website or server you have, but if it's cPanel you should see something that references "logs" on the main page of cPanel.  If's it's not cPanel, I'm not sure where to find them to be honest, heh - but they'll be somewhere.

With cPanel, you should be able to download the raw logs from the server once you click that "server logs" or "synonymous phrase including the word logs" button.  It can spit them out in a weird way in a file type you may not be familiar with like ".tar.gz".  This is just a zip type file you'll want "7-Zip" (search Google and download it) to open.  You don't necessarily need to extract the files, just "open archive" the file in windows with 7-Zip and wade through the folder layers til you come to something that probably ends in ".com".

Right click it and select "edit" from within 7-Zip and it should pop open in Notepad.  If that doesn't work, just extract that file and then rename the ending of the file to ".txt".

Now you can open it up in Notepad, and it should beautifully copy and paste into Excel.

From here in Excel select "Data" --> "Text to Columns" --> "Delimited" --> and check the bottom "custom" option and I believe a "-" dash should work well here depending upon how the server outputs the logs.

This should break everything up into different columns.  It will have every single interaction anyone has made with the server - from which pictures they've downloaded...which css files...tbey've downloaded to view your pages...everything.  It also conveniently has a timestamp, IP, referring URL, and Useragent (browser information).

Not to get too deep into Excel, but you can just select all the columns and then select "remove duplicates" under the "data" tab and only check the column with the IPs to get unique visits.  You can also use Excel's filter option on all the columns (select all the columns at the same time and click on "data" --> "filter" to see what you want.  For instance with the filter specify Excel to only show rows that do not contain ".jpg" or ".css"....etc.  Tons of options there.  Depends upon your experience with Excel though.

**I have a feeling statcounter may be what you're looking for though.**

Otherwise you could put some PHP code at the top of each page and post that to a .txt file on your server or database if you wanted.  Using relational databases and such especially just to handle what you want doesn't really become necessary until you are getting ALOT of traffic - something like 100-200 visitors per minute - and/or you're doing dynamic things with that data.

Hope this helps.  Otherwise I may have totally shot in the wrong direction with my reply - ha.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for taking the time to write that elaborate reply.I think I wasn't really clear about my needs. This is for a website that has multiple users that have their own pages, and the stats are used per page to display to the users their individual statistics for their page. While I could use something like the server's log files, it would make it much more difficult to implement than collecting the data and displaying it on demand to each user. What I'm trying to figure out is how to est store that data, db, a single flatfile or multiple flatfiles.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling I was way off ever since I read the word "relational databases" in your question.

Comment: Although I'm just making load/computer assumptions with little experience here, I'd go database with multiple flatfiles depending upon how much of a load each separate connection made on your server/db.  Otherwise I suppose a single flatfile would most likely pace things out - and traffic analytics arn't probably in that dire of need for your customers. I know if you use mysql memcached would probably come in handy as well as several other tools. It seems like a very specific & custom question to your specific situation. If you want to try giving it a shot at AWS just search for power of 60 :)